# formtastic can't convert symbol to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, formtastic

I've got a fairly simple nested form using formtastic.

My models are

```
class FieldMap < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :merge_splits
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :merge_splits

class MergeSplit < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :field_map

end
```

view is

```
<%= semantic_form_for @field_map do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :base_field, :collection => @base_fields %>
    <%= f.input :master_field, :collection =>@master_fields %>

        <%= f.semantic_fields_for :merge_split do |ms| %>
        <%= ms.input :action, :collection => @actions, :required=> false, :input_html=>{:class=>'split_merge_type', :name=>"field_map[merge_splits_attributes][action]"} %>
        <%= ms.input :character, :required=> false, :input_html=>{:class=>'split_merge_char', :name=>"field_map[merge_splits_attributes][character]"} %>
        <%= ms.input :count, :collection => [0,1], :include_blank=>false, :required=> false, :input_html=>{:class=>'split_merge_count', :name=>"field_map[merge_splits_attributes][count]"} %>
    <% end %>


    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit my form, the parameters are

```
{"utf8"=>"?",
 "authenticity_token"=>"lNinAw4DpjkIHsuUEaa0xo+sRG+qk3elA4T2VfCWgXc=",
 "field_map"=>{"base_field_id"=>"18",
 "master_field_id"=>"11",
 "merge_splits_attributes"=>{"action"=>"0",
 "character"=>"ti",
 "count"=>"0"},
 "attribute_map_attributes"=>{"attribute_id"=>""}},
 "commit"=>"Create Field map"}
```

which returns a can't convert symbol to integer error. 
Unfortunately, It doesn't tell me what it is trying to convert.

Comment: I added the view, I assume you meant the view for the form, as the error is coming from 'create'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :merge_split do |ms| %>
```

With:

```
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :merge_splits do |ms| %>
```

Just FYI, I was sure the error lied here because of the structure of your params:

```
"merge_splits_attributes"=>{"action"=>"0", "character"=>"ti", "count"=>"0"}
```

In a `has_many` relationship, the nested attributes are like this:

```
"merge_splits_attributes"=>{"0" => {"action"=>"0", "character"=>"ti", "count"=>"0" }, "1" => {"action"=>"0", "character"=>"ti", "count"=>"0" } }
```

EDIT

In your controller, I guess you do:

```
@field_map = FieldMap.new
```

Same logic, you should have the following to have a merge_split to create:

```
@field_map = FieldMap.new
@field_map.merge_splits.build
```

And remove the `:name`

Comment: that should be correct, but when I replace :merge_split with :merge_splits, the fields for the merge_splits don't show up at all. 
For some reason if the plurality of the semantic_fields_for matches the plurality of the relationship in the model, the forms don't display.
I'm not sure why that is, but this is the reason I specified the :name. 

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any merge_splits associated? I mean, when you create your object, you should build it's relationships as well otherwise they won't show up.

Comment: Sorry, but now I'm really lost. You mean have I created the associations in the model? if so, yes.